# Does the BLE spec allow for manufacturer ad type in both advertising data and scan response?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

The manufacturer specific data advertising type is a valid type in BLE spec.  My question is, can you have advertising data and scan response that both have this manufacturer advertising type?  Or are you only allowed to have one advertising type in the advertising packet (advertising data + scan response)?

The spec does not specifically say that you can't have more than one instance of this type in an advertising packet; however, it does specifically point out when it does not allow multiple instances, i.e. for Local Name:

> The Advertising and Scan Response data shall not contain more than one
>   instance of the Local Name AD type

This seems to imply that if manufacturing data is in both the advertising and scan response, it is still allowed by the spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bluetooth [CSS v6](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=302735) defines AD and their constraints.

When an AD type is forbidden in ADV or SCAN_RSP packets, or shall appear at most once, this is noted in the relevant paragraph (like for FLAGS at the end of section 1.3.1, for instance).

Here in section 1.4, there is no restriction about multiple usage of this AD, even more than once in one packet, so this is allowed.

Comment: Thanks! I verified that this is still true for Core Specification Supplement version 11 (see https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/). That said, CoreBluetooth appears to assume there's only one Manufacturer Data field in an advertisement packet.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is definitely possible. iOS devices simply concatenate the data between the adv data and scan rsp, allowing you to break up manufacturing data if it better fits your advertising structures.  It would seem that you should not do this only for name advertising types.